# i got an error i when i use google colab JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, nlp, google-colaboratory

i have home work to make an chatbot NLP. this code that i use from what the teacher gave me, i just want to change the dataset that use in it. but i got some eror because of it.

this code that i got the eror

```
# Importing the dataset
with open('Mengenal_OCD.json') as content:
  data1 = json.load(content)

# Mendapatkan semua data ke dalam list
tags = [] # data tag
inputs = [] # data input atau pattern
responses = {} # data respon
words = [] # Data kata
classes = [] # Data Kelas atau Tag
documents = [] # Data Kalimat Dokumen
ignore_words = ['?', '!'] # Mengabaikan tanda spesial karakter

for intent in data1['intents']:
  responses[intent['tag']]=intent['responses']
  for lines in intent['patterns']:
    inputs.append(lines)
    tags.append(intent['tag'])
    for pattern in intent['patterns']:
      w = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
      words.extend(w)
      documents.append((w, intent['tag']))
      # add to our classes list
      if intent['tag'] not in classes:
        classes.append(intent['tag'])

# Konversi data json ke dalam dataframe
data = pd.DataFrame({"patterns":inputs, "tags":tags})
```

and this is the eror

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-8f7f8689f064> in <module>
      1 # Importing the dataset
      2 with open('Mengenal_OCD.json') as content:
----> 3   data1 = json.load(content)
      4 
      5 # Mendapatkan semua data ke dalam list

3 frames
/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    354         except StopIteration as err:
--> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

actually i'm still learning this so i dont really know what actually wrong with it

Comment: importing json is covered in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html   ...what have you tried beyond this ?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same error if you are running colab in single shot, Do hit cells one by one.